# Laravel 5.1 subdomain unit test

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to have multiple domains in my Laravel 5.1 app

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'api.example.local'], function() {
    Route::resource('users', 'ResultController');
});

Route::group(['domain' => 'www.example.local'], function() {
    Route::resource('home', 'HomeController');
});
```

When i doing the unit test for the api.example.local

```
public function testApiCall() {
    $this->get('v1/users')->seeJson(['data' => 'users']);
}
```

However, this approach has failed and it's returning 404 request.
Therefore, i changed my test url to something like this

```
public function testApiCall() {
    $this->get('http://api.example.local/v1/users')->seeJson(['data' => 'users']);
}
```

Finally, it's green for the unit test.

I'm wondering if this is the correct way to do it?
In additional, I will have different environment, for example http://api.example.stage/v1/users. Is that means I need to change the change the url to http://api.example.stage/v1/users when I'm doing unit test for stage?

Answer (score 1):

It's almost the same for me but I'm setting ENV variables.

.env

```
FOO_DOMAIN=foo.example.com
WWW_DOMAIN=www.example.com
```

Routes

```
Route::domain(env('WWW_DOMAIN'))->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'IndexController@index')->name('index');
});

Route::domain(env('FOO_DOMAIN'))->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'FoolishController@index')->name('foolish');
});
```

Phpunit

```
$this->get('https://' . env('WWW_DOMAIN') . '/')
            ->assertSuccessful()
            ->assertSeeInOrder(['Home']);
```

Comment: why don't you use the `config`? The `config` is there exactly for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. By the way, can you give some more details on how you are doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is quite correct way to me. I do the same.

I just use `call` instead of `get`

```
$this->call('GET',...
$this->assertResponseOk();
```